# Why is mammoth unable to read the docx I've passed to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, axios, formidable

I'm trying to provide a method to upload .docx files from the client to the server using next.js. At the server, I'd like to read the .docx using the mammoth library.

**Front End Code**

```
import {
    useMantineTheme,
    rem,
    Text,
    Group
} from '@mantine/core';

import {
    IconBook,
    IconUpload,
    IconX,
} from '@tabler/icons-react';

import { 
    Dropzone, 
    FileWithPath
} from '@mantine/dropzone';

import React, { useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export default function Upload(this: any) {

    const theme = useMantineTheme();

    const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const [hash, setHash] = useState<string>("");

    async function onDrop(files : FileWithPath[]): Promise<void> {
    setIsUploading(true);

    for(const index in files) {
        const file = files[index];
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);

        try{
            await axios.post('api/pull-apart', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'content-type':'multipart/form-data'
                }
            });
        } catch(e:any) {
            console.error('There was an error uploading ', e.message);
        } finally {
            setIsUploading(false);
        }
    }
    }

    return (
    <Dropzone
        onDrop={(file) => onDrop(file)}
        onReject={(file) => console.log('rejected file', file)}
        accept={["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                "image/jpeg", "image/png"]}
        maxFiles={10}
    >
        <Group position="center" spacing="xl" style={{ minHeight: rem(80), pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
            <Dropzone.Accept>
                <IconUpload
                    size="3.2rem"
                    stroke={1.5}
                    color={theme.colors[theme.primaryColor][theme.colorScheme === 'dark' ? 4 : 6]}
                />
            </Dropzone.Accept>
            <Dropzone.Reject>
                <IconX
                    size="3.2rem"
                    stroke={1.5}
                    color={theme.colors.red[theme.colorScheme === 'dark' ? 4 : 6]}
                />
            </Dropzone.Reject>
            <Dropzone.Idle>
                <IconBook size="3.2rem" stroke={1.5} />
            </Dropzone.Idle>

            <div>
                <Text size="xl" inline>
                    Upload your .DOCX 
                </Text>
            </div>
        </Group>
    </Dropzone>
    )
}
```

**Server Code pull-apart.ts**

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import formidable, { File } from 'formidable';
import fs from 'fs';

import mammoth from 'mammoth';

const form = formidable({multiples: true});

const isFile = (file: File | File[]): file is File => !Array.isArray(file) && file.filepath !== undefined;

type Data = {
    message?: string
} | any[];

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) => {
    if(req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).json({message: "Method Not Allowed"});
    }

    try {
    const fileContent: string = await(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        form.parse(req, (err, _fields, files) => {
            if(isFile(files.file)) {
                const fileContentBuffer = fs.readFileSync(files.file.filepath);
                const fileContentReadable = fileContentBuffer.toString("utf-8");

                resolve(fileContentReadable);
            }

            reject();
        });
    }));

    /* do something */

    console.log(fileContent);

    const b = Buffer.from(fileContent, 'utf-8');

    mammoth.convertToHtml(
        {buffer: b},
        {
            styleMap: [
                "p[style-name='Title'] => h1"
            ]
        }
    ).then(function(result:any){

        var html = result.value;
        console.log(html);
    
    }).catch(function(error:any){

        console.log(error);
    
    });

    res.status(200).send({message: 'ok'});
    } catch(e) {
    res.status(400).send({message: "Bad Request"});
    }
}

export const config = {
    api: {
    bodyParser: false
    }
};

export default handler;
```

The error message output on the server console is:

```
Error: End of data reached (data length = 10142, asked index = 15447). Corrupted zip ?
```

I've double checked that my test .docx is a well-formed .docx. I assume based on the error that the issue is the interpretation of the data being passed from client to server, but I can't tell what the problem is.

As far as I can see, I'm successfully sending the file content to the server in binary form, where it's then interpreted as a string of utf-8 character. This string is then turned into a `Buffer` to be passed to Mammoth.